# Highlighting Text Under Div Tag

Tags: php, javascript, css, string, highlight

Lets say I have a div like this:

```
<div id="test" class="sourcecode">
"Some String"
</div>
```

Is it possible to have css and js to highlight a portion of that string based on a search query?

Like if I was searching for the word Stri it would just highlight that part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to divide the text, separating the highlighted part into a `<span>`. Like this.

```
<div id="test" class="sourcecode">
"Some <span style="background-color:yellow">Stri</span>ng"
</div>
```

To do characters that represent HTML tags, if you have:

```
<div id="test" class="sourcecode">
    &lt;html&gt;String&lt;/html&gt;
</div>
```

...you can highlight the same way as before:

```
<div id="test" class="sourcecode">
    <span style="background-color:yellow">&lt;html&gt;Stri</span>ng&lt;/html&gt;
</div>
```

Comment: hmm how would I go by converting everything inside a string to its character representation?

Comment: Are you using raw javascript or javascript with a library like jQuery?

Comment: For encoding the characters with jQuery, see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219860/javascript-jquery-html-encoding

Answer (score 2):

Try the [jquery.highlight](http://johannburkard.de/blog/programming/javascript/highlight-javascript-text-higlighting-jquery-plugin.html) plugin.

Make a jQuery selector containing the div in which you want to highlight some text:

```
var $div = $('#test');
```

Then run the highlight plugin with the word(s) you wish to highlight

```
$div.highlight('Stri');
```

Also you should style the class "highlight" in your css, since that's the class the highlighter will give the highlighted text:

```
.highlight
{
    background-color: yellow;
    outline: 1px solid black;
}
```

Comment: The problem that I forgot to address was how would I go about highlighting a string that has html like "<html>string</html>" where I want to highlight "<html>str" part.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="test" class="sourcecode">
"Some String"
</div>
```

in javascript after getting search result.

```
<script>
  var test = $('test').innerHtml;
  var query= 'Str';
  var new_str = test.replace(query, '<font style="background:yellow;color:red;" >'+query+'</font>');
  $('test').innerHtml = new_str;
</script>
```